# Cache tables with parallel services causing problems. unique constraint SQLException. Spring JDBC

Tags: oracle, caching, parallel-processing, spring-jdbc

Using oracle database.
Here's how i think the SQLException happens...

Say i have two instances of a service running in parallel. Both of them do the following:

1. Query cache(B) to see if Person exists there.
2. If person exists, but out of date OR doesnt exist = do a query on the main database(A).
3. If Person found in database (A) and NOT found earlier in cache (B). INSERT, else if person was found in cache earlier but was out of date UPDATE cache.

I use the following code to make the decision, based on earlier query to cache B.

```
void insertOrUpdate(RegistryPersonMo person) {
    if (person.getId() == null) {
        insertPerson(person);
    } else {
        updatePerson(person);
    }
}
```

and insert using Spring JDBC:

```
void insertPerson(RegistryPersonMo person) {
    Number id = insertInto("PERSON_REGISTRY", "RAAMAT").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("ID").executeAndReturnKey(usingParameters(person));
    if (id != null) {
        person.setId(id.longValue());
    }
}
```

The actual problem occurs when two instances of the service have finished querying the cache(B) and the person wasn't found (null). Then one instance does an INSERT, because data did not exist.The other gets SQLException upon trying to do the same, because an  entry with a unique constraint already exists.

Does anyone know what the **best\standard workaround** is? Some ideas i've had:

- Lock reading of the row until insert done. Can i do this using Spring?
- Use replace or insert with ignore. still learning, are there any downsides to these ?

Bear in mind i'd like to use  Spring and automate the query as much as possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's fine in this situation just to ignore the unique constraint exception. Yes, this is race condition but the expected one - desired outcome is achieved, record inserted. Perhaps log it to be able to assert how often this is happening.

Locking or transaction serialization would resolve this issue but won't make much sense in this case, in my opinion.

Comment: So you suggest just catching the exception?

Comment: Yes. Catch and log. Depending on your usage scenario you might almost never see it actually happening (if request for person would come randomly to one of the servers most/all of the time) or you would see it happening a lot (when requests for same person would come simultaneously to both servers). If it proves to be an issue then you might think how to address it further.